How can I create a module from a pip option when installing a Python wheel?
I'm trying to generate a Python module with information provided from the pip install command. I have project with the following structure:
top_repository/
         |/setup.py
         |/requirements.txt
         |/my_proj
                |/__init__.py
                |/__main__.py
                |/_version.py
                |/conf.py

The setup.py is:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from distutils.util import convert_path

def get_requirements():
    with open('requirements.txt') as fp:
        return fp.read()

def get_version():
    st = {}
    version_file = convert_path('my_proj/_version.py')
    with open(version_file) as f:
        exec(f.read(), st)
    return st['_version']

setup(name='my_proj',
      version=get_version(),
      description='My Proj',
      packages=find_packages(),
      zip_safe=False)

Then, I create the wheel with python setup.py bdist_wheel
I'm looking for a way to get an argument from a pip option and add the argument (say --cfg_dir) to the conf.py file during the wheel installation. For instance, if I run:
$ pip install my_proj-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl --target /usr/alternate/site-packages --cfg_dir /path/to/cfg_dir

Pip/setuptools will update the conf.py with:
CONF_DIR="/path/to/cfg_dir"

I'm using Python 3.9.18 and setuptools 53.0;0
I appreciate any help!
At this point, I have been searching around without any good pointers.

Note that distutils and using setup.py as an executable script are deprecated. Is there any reason you want to use this specific setup? (Admittedly, changing this is not likely going to provide a solution to your actual problem.)

I have no strong reason for using setup.py other than being using it successfully for a while :-) So, I'm pretty much used to it.

I'm not sure you can (since the wheel is not executed, thus code therein won't run. pip itselff won't alter files in the wheel). I'm also not sure you should: suddenly, you'd be adding random options to pip, effectively changing its interface.

It may make more sense to have users run a setup script after the installation, and put options in a user config file, which depends on the platform: on Linux, in $HOME/.config, on macOS, in $HOME/Library, not sure about Windows. In particular, because the added values are specific to the installation/platform/user, not to your project, so probably shouldn't exist in the project.
